# Action on form.addButton in suitelet 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to add a custom button in suitelet 2.0 and I want an action to be performed on click of that button.

I tried doing same like this

```
form.addButton({
                id : 'reset',
                label : 'Reset',
                functionName: 'setButton'
                });
```

But it doesn't do any action.

Answer (score 4):

If you're actually looking for a reset button, try the builtin:

```
form.addResetButton({
    label : 'Reset'
});
```

Otherwise, if you need customization

```
form.addButton({
    id : 'reset',
    label : 'Reset',
    functionName: 'setButton'
 });

form.clientScriptModulePath = 'SuiteScripts/setButton-clientscript.js';
```

With `setButton-clientscript.js` containing your function definition ala:

```
define(['N/currentRecord'],
    function(currentRecord) {
        function setButton() {
            //your code here
            //example: location.reload();
        }
        return {
            setButton: setButton
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the function in a clientscript file and then attach the clientscript to the form with:

`form.clientScriptFileId = 32;`